# Optimizing PHP-FPM Configuration for WordPress on Bitnami EC2 t3a.medium instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm running a WordPress website on an AWS EC2 t3a.medium (4Gb Ram) instance using Bitnami. The server's RAM often gets completely filled, causing the server to crash and I need to restart it from ec2 console.

That's the uptime monitor:
[image]

[image]

I've looked into tuning my php-fpm settings to mitigate this issue.

Here is the current configuration:

```
opt/bitnami/php/etc$ cat memory.conf
pm.max_children = 47
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 30
pm.max_requests = 2500
```

MariaDB configuration file:

```
[mysqladmin]
user=****************

[mysqld]
skip_name_resolve
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
basedir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb
port=3306
tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp
socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
pid_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysqld.pid
max_allowed_packet=16M
bind_address=127.0.0.1
log_error=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld_slowquery.log
long_query_time=10.0
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/lib/plugin

[client]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
default_character_set=utf8
plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/lib/plugin

[manager]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
pid_file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysqld.pid
!include /opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/bitnami/memory.conf
```

memory.conf:

```
long_query_time = 1
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
```

/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld_slowquery.log: https://pastebin.com/ZVecqAXp

Comment: You need to monitor your memory consumption. `max_children=47` feels too high for 4GB RAM.  Enable memory monitoring, drop `max_children` to 20 and watch for a week.

Comment: Thanks! With 20 children set, the services do not start. I have set it to 30 now... I will monitor it over the week and update you here

Comment: Additional DB information request about March 1, 2024, please consider from your AWS EC2,  
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide more suggestions for improving performance.

Comment: @WilsonHauck https://justpaste.it/dk6lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0.001  # to enable pre flushing
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0.001  # to reduce 1,067 dirty pages
```

Please post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%dirty%'; one day after these Global Variables are applied.

There are more opportunities to improve processing speed, after we get the dirty pages less than 7% of your buffer pool.  Please view my profile.

Comment: Thanks! With memory.conf adjusted and this the server seems to be stable.

The TEXT of result it's that: https://justpaste.it/fj0e1

Comment: @DamianoDotto  GREAT.  Have a wonderful weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I run on my t3a.nano (512MB RAM), which runs five low volume Wordpress websites, plus a few other pieces of software. The t3.medium has four times more CPU than my t3.nano and eight times more ram, so you could probably multiply these numbers by four or even eight - experimentation based on your deployment and load would be required to work this out.

If your server doesn't start when you set max_children to 20 I suspect something else is set up incorrectly. Perhaps you have some aggressive caching going on? What do the various logs say when you set max_children to 10? I don't know why you'd need to run more than 10 threads to start.

PHP 7.4

```
pm.max_children = 3
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_requests = 50
```

MySQL 8

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=50M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size=1048576
innodb_log_file_size=4194304
innodb_max_undo_log_size=10485760
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K
innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
innodb_max_undo_log_size=10485760
max_connections=20
key_buffer_size=1M

thread_stack=140K
thread_cache_size = 2
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=128K
temptable_max_ram=2097152
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
```

Comment: The advice to multiply numbers by 4 or even 8 has a nice margin of error.

Comment: True. The server in question has 8 times more RAM than mine, but only 4 times more CPU. I'll clarify.

Comment: I found this apache tools for test (stress test) the apache server:
ab -n 5000 -c 20 http://abc.xyz/index.html

Here the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html

Comment: @DamianoDotto Could you post your TEXT results of the ab stress test?

Comment: @WilsonHauck sure! That's the output: https://pastebin.com/raw/PW4HFuQw

Comment: @DamianoDotto Thank you for the ab report.  Could you also post the current bitnami php memory.conf so we see what you are running with now.

Comment: @WilsonHauck that's the running config:

pm.max_children = 24
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_requests = 1500